# Other Method for call a custom customer attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, custom-attributes, cms-block, variables

I am doing an internship in a company, and my internship supervisor wants me to display customer data.
More precisely, on the back office in the customer information there is a custom attribute that I must retrieve.
I'm still a beginner on Magento 1, so I created a tempate in :
app / design / vendor_name / default / template / cms / template.phtml
and I'm doing this:

```
$_customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customerCustomAttributeId = $_customer->getData('custom_attribute_code');
echo "<br/>";
echo $customerCustomAttributeId ;
echo "<hr/>";
```

and then I display it like this :
`{{block type="core/template" template="cms/cbr.phtml"}}` 
and it works. But my internship supervisor tells me that this is not the best method.
How could I do it otherwise? I am not asking for a solution but a clue because I am a little lost.
Hope I explained well,I'm still a beginner so there may be something that I didn't understand.
Thank you very much have a nice day.

Comment: No answer ?? :(

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't see anything wrong with the way you did it, other than some small things in your template itself (like using `$_customer->getCustomAttributeCode()` instead of `$_customer->getData('custom_attribute_code')` and writing HTML tags instead of using php to `echo` them).
Did your supervisor give any details about what they don't like about it? I mean I could see doing this as a custom widget perhaps, but the only benefit I see from that would be for whoever is creating the CMS pages/blocks you would be inserting this into.